# How to generate dynamic ui on the basis of Azure ARM template parameters in Angualr 8

Tags: typescript, azure, angular8

I want to create dynamic UI based on ARM template like azure portal do with Custom deployment
template .

Comment: would [that](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) be relevant?

Comment: @timur  no I already gone through but  not relevant. My json like below "publicIPAllocationMethod": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Dynamic",
                "Static"
            ]
        },
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": {
            "type": "string"
        }    Now I want to create one dropdown if there is allowedValues and type is equal to string present . Now one textbox if type is equal to string and allowedValues  not present. based on this kind condition.Here publicIPAllocationMethod and idleTimeoutInMinutes is like label